# Is there any marker I can set to see halfway of a mesh? I want to place another object right over

Tags: mesh

I want my object to have 4 boxes uniformly laid out, how do I make some splits or markers to tell where my boxes should go on the plane?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't think one can figure out clearly what you are talking about. Or at least a figure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very little known, even less used special feature: Snapping average.
It sets a mean location for any point you hit <kbd>A</kbd> while hovering over.

Enable snapping of the proper type. Hit <kbd>G</kbd> and move the object to a vertex and hit <kbd>A</kbd>. Repeat this process for all the other vertices that you need the average of.

Comment: Wow, nice find! I'm not too sure what the OP wants, but I can't resist giving this a +1 anyway :P

Comment: Agree. One more +1. :)   (BTW, hit A on single vertex for several times will increase the "weight", Alt A for decrease / erase. That's what I got so far) But the question itself really needs clarifying.